# Why am I suspended from chatting for a message from three months ago?

Tags: discussion, chat

I have just been suspended from chatting in the C++ lounge for a message that was deleted by the @Feeds bot, that is from May this year.  Why now the suspension (30 mins) for a message so old already?!

[image]

I'm confused.

Comment: The long arm of the law is so long, it can reach through time. (Seriously though, +1, this doesn't sound right)

Comment: Also, some random person is in the C++ lounge flagging things on a random basis it seems. That needs to STOP! Flagging should be done one a reasonable basis that what is being flagged is actually offensive, in the context that it's being written in.

Comment: Because that's how wonderful the flagging system is. You get banned when nobody even remembers what the flagged thing was actually about.

Comment: @Tony: you used a word whose whole point is to be offensive in many circles (schools, network television, most places of business...).  So you don't really have much of a leg to stand on when you get suspended (for a really nominal amount of time) for using it.  I agree with you that the lesson would have been better learned had it been delivered more proximately...but better late than never, I suppose.

Comment: This is a perfectly good and valid Meta question. That said, regarding the specific case: [expletives are not allowed on the network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233) even if zero users find them offensive.

Comment: @Popular: Whether we agree with that "decision" or not doesn't even matter here: The whole idea of blocking someone is to make them stop doing wrong in the future. Considering that, banning users for things they've done wrong months ago (and maybe haven't done since) just doesn't make sense, because it won't have stopped them doing it again five months ago.

Comment: @sbi, I know it doesn't matter. That's why I posted a throwaway comment instead of an answer. I have not stated any kind of opinion about the banning policies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[Some *teenager*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis-), who *never answered a single C++ question* on SO, and who was *never before seen in the [C++ chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)*, storms into the room, *actively searches the room's history* for words and phrases he finds offensive and then goes on a *rampage* flagging a bunch of old messages. Of course, given just sentences with words like "fuck" in it, without any textual context, room name, indeed, without even the message's date, or any other [information that would be helpful when asked to agree or disagree to a flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102604/102611#102611), enough users (of other rooms) agreed with those flags and several regulars of the C++ room (it's not only been Tony, AFAIK) got suspended for half an hour.

This whole thing is so stupid, it makes my toenails curl up in disgust.

The way the flagging system is implemented now it does more damage than it does good. It is lacking features vital for it to properly function. This is just another instance of this problem.

Also, the ability to flag messages should expire after a while, in order to prevent the community having to spend resources on issues such as this one.

Comment: [Ohhhh...if you find random cleanups stupid, wait till you see this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive)

Comment: And what will happen to me and Welbog when somebody finds Welbog's room? We'll be banned for *weeks*.

Comment: That's quite an accusation.  Do you have links or any other sources?  AFAIK, only mods and devs can see *who* flagged.

Comment: @John: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=1390167#1390167

Comment: @sbi ah, okay. Then that specific issue is already settled? Nice.

Comment: @Eat Apparently [they cannot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1861775#1861775).

Comment: @sbi Ah the poster himself is always a good source.  However, IMHO this answer still reads very much like a rant.  Given [all the recent Meta activity about digging up and flagging old posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posse), it comes as no surprise to me that that was extended to the chat rooms.  [Expletives are not allowed on SE in general](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233) if you don't want to get banned, don't break the rules.

Comment: @John Chat rooms have always been a more relaxed environment than their parent sites. If the audience *inside* the room isn't offended, I see no reason for outsiders to start flagging stuff.

Comment: @Eat and that works, as long as no outsiders (who follow stricter SO rules) come in.  But when they do, you get a meta thread asking "Why was I suspended for using language that SO doesn't tolerate?"

Comment: @John: ___1.___ I consider this decision a thoroughly stupid one, and it's not clear-cut as the mullahs would like us to believe. (Just look at the up/down ratio for the different answers.) ___2.___ What's offensive or not cannot be decided using word filters, regexes, or search phrases, and it differs between contexts, cultures, and individuals. ___3.___ Blocking a user for having said something before the ban was decided is wrong. (No, I haven't checked this case.) ___4.___ Should users be blocked at all for something they said 6 months ago? What about one year? Three years? A decade?

Comment: @John: The conclusion would be to prevent outsiders from entering chat rooms. Or prevent them from doing harm there.

Comment: @sbi **1.**  Not clear cut, *or* people simply disagree.  **2.**  If the people in charge say word *X* is against the rules, IMHO there is no problem with a regex searching for word *X*.  **3&4.**  This is SE.  Policies are applied retroactively.  (rep-recalc, anyone?)

Comment: @sbi Perhaps require a certain number of posts in a room before someone can start flagging things *in that room*?

Comment: @John: ___1.___ No idea what you're talking about. ___2.___ I will not recap arguments against word filters. Use google to find them. ___3.___ I hadn't brought it up before, and it's a good argument against retroactive bans in general. ___4.___ Did you just try to equal your rep being adjusted to you being banned from the discussion?! ___5.___ The number-of-posts rule seems reasonable. Still, blocking users for arbitrarily old messages seems wrong.

Comment: Y'all should really consider taking this discussion to (heh) [CHAT](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)

Comment: **4.**  They are not the same, but the underlying principle *is*.  As evidenced in the past, Jeff will not hesitate to retroactively enforce new policies.

Comment: @Shog Oddly, I haven't seen the usual notification for that yet...

Comment: Too many people involved. That's why I'm suggesting it. @John

Comment: @John: It's just the mechanics that is the same. And Jeff didn't hesitate to do things I disagree with in the past. That hasn't, however, stopped me from disagreeing with him and saying so. If he likes the flagging mechanism as it is, then this is another issue we disagree over.

Comment: @Shog9: The question has the "discussion" tag. What are we supposed to do except discuss it?

Comment: @DeadMG: when you're ending up with 5-point, *numbered* replies in comments, you've exhausted what comments can do for you. Also, this was getting really tangential - the question was simple enough.

Comment: @Shog9: Not that the chat would offer a better threading of arguments.

Comment: Chat actually does have *slightly* better reply indicators, which can help. But beyond that, when you're involved in a fast-paced discussion it can be used more effectively "real time" without resorting to a numbering scheme to keep track of which intra-conversation threads are being responded to. Combined, it tends to work a *little* better than comments (of course, the preferred solution for anything *important* is to just open up another meta question on the subject, but I'm not sure that's useful here).

Comment: @Shog9: So let's make the `discussion` tag a synonym of `moved-to-chat`.

Answer (score 28):

In addition to a number of other tweaks (some applied, some still planned/in-progress), there is now a moratorium in effect, to prevent flagging of old posts. *Regular* flagging is now limited to recent messages; if an old message is *so offensive* that it deserves flagging long after it is cold, the user can still flag it for moderator attention, but this is far more obvious and less an avenue for flag abuse.

We are also planning to limit the number of concurrent *unresolved* flags per user for similar reasons. See [More information is needed in chat Flagged Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102604/more-information-is-needed-in-chat-flagged-posts) for the current set of changes.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure if you're actually confused or if this is a feature-request in disguise. Somebody noticed your old message and flagged it. Flagged messages are shown to 10k users, so some of them noticed it and marked it valid. Eventually it got enough flags to be deleted, and you were banned. The same thing can happen on the main site (although you'd lose rep instead of getting banned); it's not like a message stops being offensive with age

Comment: Well... it is actually. If it wasn't offensive when it was posted,and before the eyeballs of everybody who was in chat that very moment, why is it offensive _now?_

Comment: @bad Because different people find different things offensive? In any case, your example is a message that was never offensive; Tony seems to be saying that a message that was offensive at first will somehow not be offensive four months later and should no longer be flagged

Comment: I quote from the question comments, "Flagging should be done one a reasonable basis that what is being flagged is actually offensive" - I really don't think he believes his message was offensive in the first place.

Comment: @bad Then there's an awful lot in the question about the message being old that has absolutely nothing to do with it

Comment: @Michael - I think context **DEFINES** what is offensive and inoffensive.  If we are talking about your family's business of raising plump mules and I say "Your mom has as fat ass" then it could be a compliment.  If taken **OUT OF THE CONTEXT** of that conversation it seems like an insult and/or offensive.

Comment: @JNK ...I have no idea what any of that has to do with my answer. He asked how he got suspended for such an old message, and I explained what probably happened; somehow this question morphed into huge comment threads about how broken chat flagging is. I almost never use chat flagging, and have no opinion on it either way. If it turns out the message wasn't offensive then yes, it's unfortunate that he got banned, but that's not the question

Comment: there should be a restriction on the length of time you can go back and flag.. not sure what the right time limit is - maybe 24 hrs?

Comment: @0A0D That's pretty much exactly the opposite of the argument I was making. "it's not like a message stops being offensive with age"

Comment: @Michael: Yes, you are technically correct but in the context of how the flagging action worked if the flagging only removed it from the transcript and didn't enact a ban eventually, then I don't think anyone would have a problem. But just like in real life, there are statute of limitations on certain "crimes".

Comment: @0A0D That seems sane to me; you might want to post it as a separate feature request

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I have to disagree with the statement "it's not like a message stops being offensive with age".  Words and society's acceptance of them change through time.  Take the FCC for example, it currently fines for the use of the word "dick" when used to refer to a penis, but not when referring to a detective or when speaking to someone in a pejorative manner.  That wasn't always the case.

Comment: @casperOne ...ok, but this was a couple months IIRC, not decades

Answer (score 0):

Right/wrong/rants aside, how about treating flagging like a privilege that must be earned per room? (Perhaps at least *X* posts in the room?  Maybe with *Y* starred?)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need experience in a particular room to identify offensive posts in it. It's like needing a certain amount of rep in the c++ tag before you can flag questions tagged c++

Comment: Apparently the majority opinion is that offensive is subjective.  While I don't agree, I wanted to see whether the idea of requiring experience to flag was liked or disliked.

Comment: @Michael: Because every room has its culture, and you should have a chance to get to know that culture before you decide what might be offensive? C++ is all about _facts_ (or it's on Programmers.SE), while chatting is about relaxing.

Comment: Some posts are clearly offensive and need dealing with quickly, it does not take experience in a given room to know they are offensive.   Given that rooms are public spaces, they could contain nothing that is **clearly** offensive to members of the public.

Comment: @Ian: There's more to this world than the 2 sides of your pond. There are "members of the public" who are offended by _anything_ you can think of. There's cultures that do not allow women to watch sport, those which despise mentioning "alcohol" in public, and those which disapprove of us "unbelievers" (from the POV of their religion) to publicly post our thoughts. ___Contrary to popular believe, Right Or Wrong™ is no universal truth, but a cultural artifact.___ This is an international site, open to the world, with all its cultures. [Be tolerant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106110/133368).