# Which chat message I was banned for?

Tags: support, chat, ban

I've been banned from chat for a week.

I can see that one of my chat messages from a Christianity chat room (The Upper Room) have been deleted, and I suspect that was the basis of my ban, but I can't find anything in the user interface indicating it.

Was that the message I was banned for?

**Update**: The message I was banned for:

> Homophobic, misogynist, racist, ablist people.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/

Comment: @Shog9 What is the purpose of adding that blog link? "Does this user belong here" sounds like talking about who the person is, rather than what their behaviour is.

Comment: Read it. Either you won't understand how it relates to your situation and there's no point in any of us trying to explain it, or you will and none of us will have to. Reminder: this is hardly the first time you've been warned about - or suspended for - tone-deaf comments in chat...

Comment: For the record, the "tone-deaf comments" I was warned about were in response to sexist and homophobic posts by another user.

Comment: I'm thinking that [my answer here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8620/20456) could probably apply rather well.

Comment: The original message was: "Homophobic, misogynist, racist, ablist scum." The word "scum" was later changed to "people".

Comment: @MichaelHampton "later" being during the same minute as it was posted.

Answer (score 15):

> This user has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for 6 days.

(from [your chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/11671/andrew-grimm))

You were manually suspended by a moderator; this was not an automatic ban and did not pertain to one specific message, but rather to general behavior. (Moderator tools confirm that your last flagged message was from several months ago.)

*(For the record, in this case it was for a single message, but this specific case was very severe (extremely offensive material and hate speech, [link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/15936727/history) for mods). Typically, though, a moderator will not ban a user for a single message.)*

Comment: I dispute the description of it being "very severe" and it being "extremely offensive material and hate speech". Mildly offensive, maybe.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm You know full well what you said, and you were clearly crossing the line. Please don't try to dispute what you know happened; just move on and don't post something like that again.

Comment: The last version before it was deleted: "Homophobic, misogynist, racist, ablist people."

Comment: @AndrewGrimm You call that "*mildly offensive*"? You really call that "***mildly offensive***"?!?! ... I don't know what to say about that

Comment: Yes, I call that mildly offensive. If I just called people names, or called them stupid, then maybe that'd qualify as offensive.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Wait, wait, wait. "Homophobic, misogynist, racist, ablist" is all fine and dandy, but "stupid" is offensive? I... don't see your logic here.

Comment: @Doorknob Mentioning specific problems is the basis for constructive rational discussion, while calling names isn't.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - I can confirm that doorknob's reasoning is correct.  It was the blanket characterization of an entire group of people in a negative manner.  That's basically the definition of hate speech.  Targeted at one person is far less offensive than when targeted against an entire people group.

Comment: @user0000000: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105053/133368

Comment: @user0000000 the message this is about is from yesterday.