# Disable flagging on old chat messages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, chat

In response to the effect [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105053/139168) is referring, I am proposing one of two possible scenarios:

1. Disallow flags on chat messages older than X hours, or
2. Remove old flagged posts from the transcript, but no suspension occurs (as in the aforementioned question).

Comment: If only we weren't having these issues *only in the C++ room*...

Comment: It's not just a C++ room problem....... Haters gonna hate.

Comment: I remember when we were annoyed by the Android and PHP rooms generating too many flags as well. We didn't get very vocal at the time, because we were not aware of all the nooks and crannies of the system, and well, it wasn't with us. Now that it hit us, we got vocal (whiny?).

Comment: @balpha: What Martinho says. This is not a C++ room problem ([this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102604/133368) was triggered by flags happening in other rooms, IIRC). We might be louder about it than other rooms, but that's just because we care more. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

[This was done a few weeks after it was suggested.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102604/more-information-is-needed-in-chat-flagged-posts/107183#107183)