# How can messages in a chat transcript be flagged?

Tags: support, chat-flags, chat-transcript

For messages in chat, clicking on the drop-down icon will allow rude or abusive messages to be flagged. I've noticed that messages in a transcript can no longer be flagged. I seem to recall that it used to be possible. How can one flag a problematic message that is in a transcript for abuse or mod attention?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I am asking how to flag comments, not whether or not it's right to flag a comment that is moved from a question/answer thread to chat. In particular, the answer says _I'd recommend that you flag the post the comments were on for moderator attention_, which is not the case for chat comments which are not linked under any given question or answer. As such, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The answer to that post says what to do: flag the post the comments were on initially, and clearly state that those comments were moved to chat.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Which is impossible for comments in chat which are not under any post. Take for example the Stack Overflow JavaScript chat (just an example). What post is it under that I would flag if a comment in the chat is abusive?

Comment: You mean chat *messages*? *Comments* refer only to comments on posts, and a "comment in chat" means "comment that was moved to chat".

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Ah, I'm using the terminology wrong. I'll edit, thanks!

Comment: @rene Messages that are not in a transcript, yes. I've considered doing a raw POST request since I'm pretty sure the button was simply removed, but the API is confusing.

Comment: Per the linked-linked answer, messages older than 15 days cannot be flagged.

Comment: *The API is confusing* ... which API?  ... The non-existing Chat-API? ... It is confusing that it doesn't exist. I give you that.

Comment: @rene Well I mean the POST syntax used by the client-side JavaScript.

Comment: You're not supposed to reverse engineer these things and hack yourself into the site ;) ... cheers!

Comment: @rene Well there's nothing wrong with reverse engineering client-side JavaScript, at least. But I will stay within the bounds of the CFAA/site ToS and will not try to hack this site or violate any security barriers.

Comment: Related: https://stackapps.com/questions/8336/stack-exchange-chat-api-documentation-and-bot-boilerplate-finally

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, at least not from the transcript.

A workaround is to join the room, and keep loading older messages until you get to the message you want to flag. Only moderator flags will work, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107183/295232):

> a moratorium on messages over, say, 10 days old; if it wasn't flagged as part of the live active discussion, then flagging it after the fact is probably so rare that disallowing that (leaving only mod-flags, which are more obvious when abused) seems reasonable **[done - 15 days currently, but open to review]**

If the room has a lot of messages, the message is really old and/or you don't want to join the room, there's an alternative: flag a post on the site the chatroom is associated with and clearly state there's nothing wrong with the post itself, but a ♦ moderator should have a look at the chat message you actually would like to flag. It's probably a good idea to state *why* you're using a custom flag.

Comment: Is the check (for automated flagging) done server-side or client-side?

Comment: I have no idea (and don't have time to test right now).

Comment: Actually, I've tested this before: while your flag will initially appear to go through, when you refresh the page, it will have disappeared. So there is a server-side validation.